# Sum + Pivot + Where calculation in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot, where-clause, sumifs

I'm new to SQL and tried searching for a post mappable to my own, but could not find one, so any advice would be really appreciated!

I have a dataset that looks like this (but ~25 million rows):

```js
ID Date Amount Type
112233 12/1/2018 300 3
112233 12/1/2018 80 3
112233 12/1/2018 60 0
112233 12/1/2018 40 3
112233 12/1/2018 20 3
112233 12/1/2018 40 3
112233 12/1/2018 0 0
112233 12/2/2018 120 3
112233 12/2/2018 120 3
112233 12/2/2018 120 0
112233 12/2/2018 120 3
112233 12/3/2018 120 3
112233 12/3/2018 120 0
112233 12/3/2018 120 0
112233 12/3/2018 120 3
112233 12/3/2018 120 3
112233 12/3/2018 120 3
112233 12/3/2018 120 3
666600 12/1/2018 0 0
666600 12/1/2018 0 0
666600 12/1/2018 100 3
666600 12/1/2018 400 3
666600 12/1/2018 80 3
666600 12/1/2018 40 3
666600 12/1/2018 0 0
666600 12/2/2018 80 3
666600 12/2/2018 0 0
666600 12/2/2018 80 3
666600 12/2/2018 0 0
666600 12/2/2018 500 0
666600 12/2/2018 100 3
666600 12/3/2018 400 3
666600 12/3/2018 80 3
666600 12/3/2018 40 3
666600 12/3/2018 0 0
666600 12/3/2018 80 3
666600 12/4/2018 0 0
666600 12/4/2018 80 3
```

and I need it to look like this:

```js
ID Amount Type
112233 420 0
112233 1,440 3
666600 500 0
666600 1,560 3
```

In excel terms, what I want to do is: a SUMIFS function, summing 'Amount' by 'ID' (in this example 112233 and 666600) and by 'Type' (either 0 or 3).

Is this doable in SQL? Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I keep getting this error:

"Column 'Database.dbo.Table.Column' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: . . You should show your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following solution:

```
SELECT ID, Sum(Amount) as 'Amount', Type
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ID, Type;
```

Comment: Wow, that was MUCH simpler than what I was attempting. Thank you so much Aura, this is awesome!